# Google Colab Unrecognized Runtime

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

This might be a dumb question but I'm using Google Colab to host notebooks for my students.  I create the notebooks in a local Anaconda Python 3 environment, and when I upload them to Google Colab this warning pops up:

[image]

I know that it won't cause problems, and the notebook will run just fine.  But is there a way to change the the notebook runtime to Python 3 so my students don't see this message and panic?

Comment: Does this message persist if you select File -> Make a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the notebook with a text editor. It's just a json file.

You can edit it, change `conda-env-py3-py` to `python3`